# Angular ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, typescript

Buenas en la consola del navegador me aparece esto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi codigo en Angular es el siguiente

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <form #registerForm="ngForm" class="col-lg-10">
                <p>
                    <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.name" class="form-control"
                        required />
                    <span *ngIf="!name.valid && name.touched"> El nombre es obligatorio</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Apellidos</label>
                    <input type="text" name="surname" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.surname" class="form-control"
                        required />
                    <span *ngIf="!surname.valid && surname.touched"> El Apellido es obligatorio</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="nick">Nick</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nick" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.nick" class="form-control"
                        required />
                    <span *ngIf="!nick.valid && nick.touched"> El nick es obligatorio</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.email" class="form-control"
                        required pattern="/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/" />
                    <span *ngIf="!email.valid && email.touched"> El email es obligatorio</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.password" class="form-control"
                        required />
                    <span *ngIf="!password.valid && password.touched"> El password es obligatorio</span>
                </p>
                <input type="submit" value="{{title}}" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!registerFrom.form.valid" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tengo un componente donde cargo el usuario

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../../models/user';

@Component({
    selector: 'register',
    templateUrl: './register.component.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

    title: string;
    user: User;
    constructor(
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _router: Router
    ) {
        this.title = "Registrate";
        this.user = new User("","","","","","","","");
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Componente del Registro cargado...');

    }
}
```

Y este es el modelo del usuario

```
export class User{
    constructor(
        id:string,
        name:string,
        surname:string,
        nick:string,
        email:string,
        password:string,
        role:string,
        image:string,
    ){}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supongo que has cogido el ejemplo de los Template Forms del tutorial de Angular y has intentado generalizar. Si es así, es normal que te equivoques porque el ejemplo no es muy bueno y da pie a equívocos:

```
<p>
    <label for="name">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.name"
           class="form-control" required />
    <span *ngIf="!name.valid && name.touched"> El nombre es obligatorio</span>
</p>
```

Este primer campo está bien: su nombre es name, por lo que tienes los atributos `name="name"` y `#name="ngModel"`. Así sale en muchos ejemplo y es la fuente de los errores:

```
<p>
    <label>Apellidos</label>
    <input type="text" name="surname" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.surname" class="form-control" required />
    <span *ngIf="!surname.valid && surname.touched"> El Apellido es obligatorio</span>
</p>
```

El campo en este caso se llama surname, por lo que debería ser así:

```
<p>
    <label>Apellidos</label>
    <input type="text" name="surname" #surname="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.surname" class="form-control" required />
    <span *ngIf="!surname.valid && surname.touched"> El Apellido es obligatorio</span>
</p>
```

Fíjate en el `#surname="ngModel"`, ése es el fallo que tienes: todos los campos se asocian a `name`